# How to Downgrade from Helm3 to Helm2?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I am trying to downgrade helm version from version 3 to 2, but could not get a very concrete answer on how it can be done. It would be great if someone can share something. 
I have installed helm using snap on a RHEL machine.

Comment: Helm3 should be able to install Helm2 charts as well.Do you have any specific reason for the downgrade ?

Comment: I was installing storageOS on kubernetes using there official helm chart and it seems helm2 charts are not backward compatible on helm 3. So, thats the reason i wanted to downgrade.